# LWUIT item question

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have a standard `com.sun.lwuit.list`. I can get the selected item using methods `getSelectedItem` or `getSelectedIndex`. The item is a picture and two labels. How do I know if I clicked on the picture or on one of the labels. I admit that it is possible to pass the click event to a child components or perhaps may exists a method for finding component by current mouse coordinates.

```
public class NewsFeedListRender extends Container implements ListCellRenderer 
{
    private final Container newsFeedCont = new Container();
    private final Container pictureCont = new Container();
    private final Label name = new Label();
    private final Label message = new Label();
    private final Label picture = new Label();
    private final Label data    = new Label();
            ....

    public NewsFeedListRender() 
    {   
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        newsFeedCont.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pictureCont.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        Style s = name.getStyle();
        s.setFont(font_large);          

        s = message.getStyle();
        s.setFont(font_small);

        s = data.getStyle();
        s.setFont(font_mini);
                .....
            }

   }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) 
    {       
        if (value instanceof MessageItem) 
        {           
            MessageItem newsFeedData = (MessageItem) value;
            if (newsFeedData.getSender() != null)
            {
                if (newsFeedData.getSender().getName() != null)
                    name.setText(newsFeedData.getSender().getName()); //fixthis
            }
            else
            {
                name.setText("Unknown sender");
            }
            if(newsFeedData.getMessage() != null)
                message.setText(newsFeedData.getMessage());
            else
            {
                message.setText("Default message");
            }

            try 
            {
                data.setText(newsFeedData.getDataReceive().toString());
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }                               
            Image img = null;
            img = newsFeedData.getSender().getIcon();
            if( img != null)
            {
                picture.setIcon(img);
            }
                        .......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSelectedItem()` returns the `Container` object and you can count the value of the `Container` object. Then you need to get the what are the components you are added into this container. See the sample code,

```
Container con = (Container) list.getSelectedItem();
for(int i = 0; i < con.getComponentCount(); i++){
Object obj = (Object) con.getComponentAt(i); // typecast component name instead object
}
```

Comment: I already know what components include in item. I want to know how determinate if I clicked on the picture or on one of the labels ?

Comment: AFAIK You add the listener for list. So you can't find which component you are clicked in the list item.